# How do I retexture a sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

As far as I can tell, the Birch Sign just uses the Birch Planks texture. So, if I were to want a sign made of wool, I would change the texture for Birch Planks to wool. However, I did this, and the sign didn't change. Since there's no "Birch Wood Sign" texture in the "block" folder, how would I go about changing a sign?

Comment: Have you tried a block model? I think there's something special with signs, because of their tile entity renderer, but it might work.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm not very adept at making resource packs, but from my exploring in the files I found JSONs for all the blocks. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I'm not good at it either, I would suggest just googling example resource packs with block models and playing around with them. I have also heard of a model creator by "MrCrayfish", but I don't know if it's updated to the current versions.

Answer (score 0):

The textures for the signs are in their own folder in the "entity" folder, which is in the "textures" folder.